# What file systems can be used for checkpointing

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, checkpointing

The documentation says that any Hadoop API compatible file systems ( like HDFS , S3 ) can be used as checkpoint directory.

My question is that apart from HDFS and S3 what are other practical alternatives for a spark streaming application using Kafka and Cassandra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type of distributed file system like [Gluster](https://www.gluster.org/), [GFS](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs.html), [Luster](http://lustre.org/) and many more but provided the protocol used by the underlying filesystem should be supported by Spark API's.